# How to get around Agda module parameter inflexibility?

Tags: parameters, module, agda

I was wondering if anyone has a solution for the following problem in Agda. I would like to pass in a natural number `n` as a parameter to an Agda module. Within this module I construct a function that takes an argument of type `Fin n`. When the pattern matches the argument to this function, I get the problem that `n` might be `zero` and therefore the type `Fin n` will be empty. Agda will not accept the `zero` and `suc _` constructors for Fin n.

The weird thing is that when you introduce the original natural number in the function itself, Agda doesn't seem to have this problem and the function compiles fine.

Below is a minimal example:

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Fin
open import Data.Bool

module Test (n : ℕ) where

  -- Compiles
  isZero₁ : ∀ {m : ℕ} → Fin m → Bool
  isZero₁ zero = true
  isZero₁ (suc _) = false

  -- Does not compile with error: "suc n₁ != n of
  -- type ℕ when checking that the pattern zero has type Fin n"
  isZero₂ : Fin n → Bool
  isZero₂ zero = true
  isZero₂ (suc _) = false
```

In the real module I pass in 5 other parameters that depend on `n`. Therefore I **do** need to supply `n` as a parameter. At the same time I also need to be able to write functions that pattern match on objects of type `Fin n`. Anyone have any ideas how I might do this?

Comment: Is defining `isZero₂` in terms of `isZero₁` not an option?

Comment: `isZero₁ zero = ...` is the same as `isZero₁ {suc m} zero = ...`. How would you rewrite `isZero₂` in the same way? `n` is free in `isZero₂` and [can't become non-free](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/1342).

Comment: @user3237465 `isZero₂ = isZero₁ {n}`. I have no idea what your actual code looks like, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ulf](https://github.com/UlfNorell) has been working on a fix for that particular problem today. It should land in master pretty soon. In the meantime, you will have to define `isZero₁` where the variable in question has been generalised and then use to get `isZero₂`

```
isZero₂ : Fin n → Bool
isZero₂ = isZero₁
```

Because writing down the type for your more general functions can be a bit annoying, you can use `C-c C-h` which helps you generate the type of auxiliary functions. Write `isZero` but without filling in the body, go in the hole, type the name of your auxiliary function and the arguments you'd like it to be applied to and then `C-c C-h` will generate a type for you. For instance, given the source file:

```
isZero : Fin n → Bool
isZero = {! auxiliary !}
```

If you go in the hole and type `C-c C-h`, you'll get:

```
auxiliary : ∀ {n} → Fin n → Bool
```

in the `AgdaInfo` buffer.

Comment: You could also try "isZero i with n"

Comment: Good to know it's being worked on! I guess I'll define the second in terms of the first as you and @Vitus suggest. It's not ideal as, because of all the extra  parameters, `isZero₁` is very messy but it'll do for now. Thanks!

Comment: @user2667523 I have edited the answer to explain how to use `C-c C-h` to generate the type of such auxiliary functions. ;)